# Flask in docker working very slowly and not synch files

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've 2 problems with flask app in docker. Application working slowly and freeze after finish last request (for example: first route work fine, next click other link/page app freeze. If i go to homepage via URL and run page again working ok ). Outside docker app working very fast.
Second problem is docker not synch files in container after change files.

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.9

# set work directory
WORKDIR /base

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /base/requirements.txt
COPY ./base_app.py /base/base_app.py
COPY ./config.py /base/config.py
COPY ./certs/ /base/certs/
COPY ./app/ /base/app/
COPY ./tests/ /base/tests/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# docker-compose
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/app/:/usr/src/app/
    networks:
      - flask-network
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - flaskdb

  flaskdb:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/postgres_database:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - flask-network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always

networks:
   flask-network:
        driver: bridge
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of significant errors in the code you show.

The first problem is that your application doesn't run at all: the Dockerfile is missing the `CMD` line that tells Docker what to run, and you override it in the Compose setup with a meaningless `tail` command.  You should generally set this in the Dockerfile:

```sh
CMD ["./base_app.py"]
```

You can remove most of the Compose settings you have.  You do not need `command:` (it's in the Dockerfile), `volumes:` (what you have is ineffective and the code is in the image anyways), or `networks:` (Compose provides a network named `default`; delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the file).

> Second problem is docker not synch files in container after change files.

I don't usually recommend trying to do actual development in Docker.  You can tell Compose to just start the database

```sh
docker-compose up -d flaskdb
```

and then you can access it from the host (`PGHOST=localhost`, `PGPORT=5432`).  This means you can use an ordinary non-Docker Python virtual environment for development.

If you do want to try to use `volumes:` to simulate a live development environment (you talk about performance; this specific path can be quite slow on non-Linux hosts) then you need to make sure the *left* side of `volumes:` is the host directory with your code (probably `.`), the *right* side is the container directory (your Dockerfile uses `/base`), and your Dockerfile doesn't rearrange, modify, or generate the files at all (the bind mount hides all of it).

```yaml
# don't run the application in the image; use the Docker infrastructure
# to run something else
volumes:
  # v-------- left side: host path (matches COPY source directory)
  - .:/base
  #    ^^^^-- right side: container path (matches WORKDIR/destination directory)
```

Comment: I add tail because so far I'm running app manually inside the container. I del network from docker-compose and change volumes ( .:/base ). I understand that live refresh is slower. But even my other django application runs many times faster than this one :(